# Function in Scheme that shows the minimum and the maximum numbers (integers) in a list

Tags: scheme

Is there a way to make a function in Scheme that receives a list of numbers (integers) and then it creates a list with the maximum and minimum numbers of that list ?

I know how to make a function for each maximum,

```
(define (mini a)
 (if (null? (cdr a)) (car a) 
  (min (car a) (mini(cdr a))) 
 )
)
```

and mininum:

```
(define (maxi a)
 (if (null? (cdr a)) (car a) 
  (min (car a) (maxi(cdr a))) 
 )
)
```

What i want is one function to do both, in the simplest way possible, because i'm very new to this paradigm.

Comment: you just need a recursive accumulator to do this. just think about how you will do in other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're pretty close. Just use the functions you already have.

```
(define (maximini a) (list (maxi a) (mini a)))
```

A big part of writing good scheme programs is decomposing functionality into separate, reusable procedures. Encapsulating the min and max behaviour is a mixture of concerns.

If there is a limitation of one traversal

```
(define (min a b) (if (< a b) a b))
(define (max a b) (if (> a b) a b))

(define (maximini a)
  (let loop [(x -inf.0) (y +inf.0) (a a)]
    (if (empty? a)
        (list x y)
        (loop (max (car a) x) (min (car a) y) (cdr a)))))

(maximini '(-4 3 2 1 10 -5))
; => '(10 -5)
```

Comment: i believe op means one traversal to do both.

Comment: thank you very much, so obvious that i couldn't see.

Comment: Alas, using initial values of `-inf.0` and `+inf.0` forces everything to be inexact. :-( Try `(max -inf.0 0)` and see what you get in return.

Comment: `(max -inf.0 0)` returns 0 ?

Comment: can u pls explain what this if does ? "(if (< a b) a b))"

Comment: @naomik Interesting, [that's not what rudybot told me](https://botbot.me/freenode/racket/msg/63403827/). Maybe rudybot is running an older version of Racket? \*checks\* (Update: it currently runs 6.2.1.)

Comment: @Gouki0 "if a is less than b return a otherwise return b"

Comment: Why do you reimplement the standard procedures `max` and `min`?

Comment: @Sylwester mostly for clarity's sake, to show precisely what's going on. I felt the code stood a little better as an isolated example. Not to mention, if you're unaware of a particular built-in, it's good to not be afraid to implement it on your own. That way we don't have to develop a dependence on language designers.

Comment: As a positive side-effect, it turns out that the built-in `max` has a strange behaviour, as identified by @ChrisJester-Young. Built-in `(max -inf.0 0)` will return `0.0` but mine will return `0`.

Comment: @naomik Yup, thats in the scheme report since inexact zero can be both larger and smaller than exact zero, which can be said to any number. The report allows exact answers only when you can guarantee it which racket clearly doesn't :-)

Answer (score 2):

You make a helper that has the list and two variables, one for max and one for minimum. You start it off with `max` and `min` being the value of the first element and you iterate the rest by using the procedures `max` and `min` to the new element with the current max/min. When you hit the end of the list you return the variables that will hold the min and max value.

So it will look somethng like this:

```scm
(define (min-max lst)
  (let helper ((lst (cdr lst)) (cur-min (car lst)) (cur-max (car lst)))
    (if (null? lst)
        (values cur-min  cur-max)
        (helper (cdr lst)
                (min cur-min (car lst))
                (max cur-max (car lst))))))
```

Comment: (define (maximini a) 
(define (mini a)
(if (null? (cdr a)) (car a)
(min (car a) (mini(cdr a)))
)
)
 (define (maxi a)
     (if (null? (cdr a)) (car a)
      (max (car a) (maxi(cdr a)))
     )
    )
   
 (list (maxi a) (mini a))
 
)

Comment: @Gouki0 That will work too, but it does it by iterating twice instead of once. For small lists (below a million elements) you probably won't notice much difference.

Comment: What would be a good way to make this procedure compatible with empty lists?

Comment: @naomik IMO thats magic casting, which I don't like. I can be convinced `car` and `cdr` to return `()` for empty lists like CL does and that all scalars have length of `1` like in perl6, but what would be the minimum and maximum of a list with *no numbers*? It's certainly not negative/positive infinitive since that doesn't make sense at all. If you need a first value you expose the helpers arguments and either require them filled in or at least one element in the list.

Comment: Compelling reasoning. I like it and it makes sense. I will make better attempts to remember this sort of thing when designing my own procedures.